# Threading using a producer and consumer threads in an infinte loop

Tags: python, mongodb, multithreading

I am not much familiar with threading.
I want to run two threads in an infinite loop. The first thread will be producing some data. The second thread takes the data and checks whether the data being sent satisfies a condition then it will be sent to database. Otherwise, the database will not be updated. I have implemented in such a way that I put all the incoming data into a queue and the second thread takes the data and checks the data for the condition.
Another way is put only those data in the queue which satisfies the condition, so in the second thread no need to check the condition.
I implemented in the first way. But it didn't work. The data will be coming at high speed and I have to update the database according to the incoming data.

Please suggest an effective way to implement this in threading. Also I have seen `condition_object.wait()`, `condition_object.acquire()`, `condition_object.release()` for implementing this type of thread. But I don't know how to use it.

```
class Producer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, parser, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.parser = parser

    def run(self):

        while True:
            parsedData = self.parser.readAndParseUart()
            targets = parsedData[0]
            data = parsedData[1]
            db = parsedData[3]
            indexes = parsedData[2]
            d = [data, db, targets, indexes]
            self.queue.put(d)
            print("thread 1 completed")
            time.sleep(1)


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):

        while True:
            p = self.queue.get()
            targets = p[2]
            indexes = p[3]
            data = p[0]
            db = p[1]
            if indexes != []:

                for l in range(len(targets[0])):
                    db.Updated.find_one_and_update(
                        {"name": str(targets[0][l])},
                        {
                            "$set": {
                                "date&time": targets[16],
                                "x": targets[1][l],
                                "y": targets[2][l],
                                "z": targets[3][l],
                            }
                        },
                        upsert=True,
                    )
                rec_id1 = db.History.insert_many(data)
            self.queue.task_done()


def main():
    parser = uartParserSDK()
    queue = Queue()
    t1 = Producer(parser, queue)
    t2 = Consumer(queue)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it didn't work"? At a quick glance, it looks like that code should be fine.

Comment: It worked. But the data being updated is at a very slow rate. Is it possible to increase the speed of updating the database?

Comment: Well, you are waiting a second between each read?

Comment: Even if we remove the delay the updating the database is slow.